# IOException when trying to fetch json data

Tags: android, json, bufferedinputstream, jsonreader

I am using the following method to fetch my json data:

```
private JsonReader getJsonData(String link) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(link);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

        //Log.e("Output", printOutput(is));
        reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

    } catch (NullPointerException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Snackbar.make(layout, Constants.SERVER_ERROR, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return reader;
}
```

It was working fine and was parsing correctly. But now i get the following error on the logs.

```
09-17 14:53:39.082  24761-28286/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException: closed
09-17 14:53:39.088  24761-28286/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:164)
09-17 14:53:39.088  24761-28286/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
09-17 14:53:39.088  24761-28286/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:231)
09-17 14:53:39.088  24761-28286/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.fillBuffer(JsonReader.java:1263)
09-17 14:53:39.088  24761-28286/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextNonWhitespace(JsonReader.java:1309)
09-17 14:53:39.088  24761-28286/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.consumeNonExecutePrefix(JsonReader.java:1514)
09-17 14:53:39.088  24761-28286/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:523)
09-17 14:53:39.088  24761-28286/com.radioafrica.music W/System.err﹕ at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:368)
```

What could be issue?

Comment: Add catch for IOException

Comment: your json is not proper... try to log the response string

Comment: @AngadTiwari I have caught the IOException as indicated above. The response string is as follows

`{"tracks":{"track":[{"name":"Can't Feel My Face","duration":"0","playcount":"912967","listeners":"208431","mbid":"","url":"http://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd/_/Can%27t+Feel+My+Face","streamable":{"#text":"0","fulltrack":"0"},"artist":{"name":"The Weeknd","mbid":"c8b03190-306c-4120-bb0b-6f2ebfc06ea9","url":"http://www.last.fm/music/The+Weeknd"},"image":[{"#text":"http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/34s/1d6fb4d0e9174fb7cf123de2de1b55b8.png","size":"small"},{"#text":"http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/64s/1d6.....`

Comment: try to check whether this json is valid or not...usin pro.jsonlint.com

Comment: the issue is most likely this: you return a json reader on an opened stream. What that means is that the reader will continue to receive content. then you close the connection in the finally block. the reader is no longer valid, and crashes next time you try to read stuff from it.

Comment: @njzk2 So i should close the connection after the reader is done parsing the data?

Comment: yes. or read the data completely and then close the connection

Comment: @njzk2 It worked, thanks!!